# .NET Core CoreFX Runtime Adaption Layer purpose

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been trying to find some more information on CoreFX part of .NET Core and mainly on the Runtime Adaption Layer. This adaption layer is mentioned on .NET Core diagrams (e.g. [image: http://windowshostasp.net/wp-content/uploads/aspnet-51.jpg], but I did not found single description of purpose of this layer, so I would like to ask for explanation of this layer. Thank you.

Comment: This is a rather old diagram (since it mentions ASP.NET 5). However, my guess is that it contains the runtime (OS) specific implementations of the APIs in .NET Standard (the 'Unified BCL') such as networking and file systems.

Comment: Thanks Henk, but if I understand correctly Unified BCL is not the same thing as .NET Standard. Please correct me if I am wrong. Please see: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Comment: What makes you think that? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx is the .NET Core BCL/FCL, not a unified one. .NET Standard unifies the BCLs from different platforms (e.g. Desktop .NET, .NET Core, Mono).

Comment: So in other words, CoreFX contains both APIs or Class Libraries defined within .NET Standard and APIs specific for .NET Core. Is that correct?

Comment: @marek_lani -  Not really. `.NET Standard` is an `"API spec"`, that seeks to resolve inconsistencies between all the pre-existing variations on .NET (including Mono) such that there is a spec that is supported by all up-to-date versions of .NET. `.NET Core` is an *"implementation of that spec"*, that eventually will be the *only* .NET that is recommended for new projects. .NET Standard has gone through multiple versions, each with a corresponding .NET Core implementation. At each version of the API, additional functionality from the various families of .NET was added.

Comment: ... with the upcoming release of `.NET 5` (they've dropped the word "Core" because it is feature-complete) Microsoft states that the API is now sufficient: that there is no longer reason for anyone to stay on the older .NET technologies (.NET Framework, Mono, Xamarin). [More accurately, the essential mobile parts of Xamarin that made it valuable, are part of .NET 5. I imagine there will still be a thinner "Xamarin" that adds additional APIs, but is entirely optional.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right, Runtime Adaption Layer is known as Platform Adaptation (Abstraction) Layer (PAL).

According to [.NET Core glossary](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/glossary.md)

> PAL provides an abstraction layer between the runtime and the
>   operating system.

The implementation for BCL (CoreFX) apparently could be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Common/src/Interop

CoreCLR btw has its own PAL

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/pal

https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/src/corehost/common/pal.h (corehost actually, not CLR)

Worth to mention ([from here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/03/04/rotor.html)) that PAL has Win32 API syntax

> The PAL exposes a collection of interfaces that are based on Win32